# Java Benchmark for recursive stairs climbing puzzle

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

This now very common algorithm question was asked by a proctor during a whiteboard exam session. My job was to observe, listen to and objectively judge the answers given, but I had neither control over this question asked nor could interact with the person answering. 
There was five minutes given to analyze the problem, where the candidate could write bullet notes, pseudo code (this was allowed during actual code-writing as well as long as it was clearly indicated, and people including pseudo-code as comments or TODO tasks before figuring out the algorithm got bonus points).

- **"A child is climbing up a staircase with n steps, and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps at a time. Implement a method to count how many possible ways the child can jump up the stairs."**

The person who got this question couldn't get started on the recursion algorithm on the spot, so the proctor eventually piece-by-piece led him to HIS solution, which in my opinion was not optimal (well, different from my chosen solution making it difficult to grade someone objectively with respect to code optimization).

**Proctor:**

```
public class Staircase {

public static int stairs;

public Staircase() {

    int a = counting(stairs);
    System.out.println(a);

}

static int counting(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return counting(n - 1) + counting(n - 2) + counting(n - 3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Staircase child;
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        stairs = i;
        child = new Staircase();            
    }
    System.out.println("Time:" + ((System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000));

}
}

//
```

**Mine:**

```
public class Steps {

public static int stairs;
int c2 = 0;

public Steps() {

    int a = step2(0);
    System.out.println(a);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Steps steps;
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        stairs = i;
        steps = new Steps();
    }
    System.out.println("Time:" + ((System.nanoTime() - t1) / 1000000));
}

public int step2(int c) {

    if (c + 1 < stairs) {
        if (c + 2 <= stairs) {
            if (c + 3 <= stairs) {
                step2(c + 3);
            }
            step2(c + 2);
        }
        step2(c + 1);
    } else {
        c2++;
    }
    return c2;
}
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
**Proctor:** Time: 356
**Mine:** Time: 166

Could someone clarify which algorithm is better/ more optimal? The execution time of my algorithm appears to be less than half as long, (but I am referencing and updating an additional integer which i thought was rather inconsequential) and it allows for setting arbitrary starting and ending step without needing to first now their difference (although for anything higher than n=40 you will need a beast of a CPU).

My question: (feel free to ignore the above example) How do you properly benchmark a similar recursion-based problem (tower of Hanoi etc.). Do you just look at the timing, or take other things into consideration (heap?).

Comment: Not really answering your question but as far as I know there is a O(log n) solution to this problem via matrix exponentiation. Something similar to the matrix exponentiation solution for Fibonacci.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Teaser: You may perform this computation easily in less than one millisecond. Details follow...

---

### Which one is "better"?

The question of which algorithm is "better" may refer to the execution time, but also to other things, like the implementation style.

The `Staircase` implementation is shorter, more concise and IMHO more readable. And more importantly: It does not involve a ***state***. The `c2` variable that you introduced there destroys the advantages (and beauty) of a purely functional recursive implementation. This may easily be fixed, although the implementation then already becomes more similar to the `Staircase` one.

---

### Measuring performance

Regarding the question about execution time: Properly measuring execution time in Java is tricky.

Related reading:

- [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)
- [Java theory and practice: Anatomy of a flawed microbenchmark](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02225/)
- [HotSpot Internals](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Home)

In order to properly and reliably measure execution times, there exist several options. Apart from a profiler, like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), there are frameworks like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) or [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/), but admittedly, using them may be some effort.

For the *simplest* form of a very basic, manual Java Microbenchmark you have to consider the following:

- Run the algorithms multiple times, to give the JIT a chance to kick in
- Run the algorithms alternatingly and not only one after the other
- Run the algorithms with increasing input size
- Somehow save and print the results of the computation, to prevent the computation from being optimized away
- Don't print anything to the console *during* the benchmark
- Consider that timings *may* be distorted by the garbage collector (GC)

Again: **These are only rules of thumb**, and there may still be unexpected results (refer to the links above for more details). But with this strategy, you usually obtain a good indication about the performance, and at least can see whether it's likely that there *really* are significant differences between the algorithms.

---

### The differences between the approaches

The `Staircase` implementation and the `Steps` implementation are not very different.

The main conceptual difference is that the `Staircase` implementation is counting **down**, and the `Steps` implementation is counting **up**.

The main difference that actually affects the performance is how the *Base Case* is handled (see [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) on Wikipedia). In your implementation, you avoid calling the method recursively when it is not necessary, at the cost of some additional `if` statements. The `Staircase` implementation uses a very generic treatment of the base case, by just checking whether `n < 0`.

One could consider an "intermediate" solution that combines ideas from both approaches:

```
class Staircase2
{
    public static int counting(int n)
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (n >= 1) 
        {
            result += counting(n-1);
            if (n >= 2) 
            {
                result += counting(n-2);
                if (n >= 3) 
                {
                    result += counting(n-3);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result += 1;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It's still recursive without a state, and sums up the intermediate results, avoiding many of the "useless" calls by using some `if` queries. It's already noticably faster than the original `Staircase` implementation, but still a tad slower than the `Steps` implementation.

---

### Why both solutions are slow

For both implementations, there's not really anything to be computed. The method consists of few `if` statements and some additions. The most expensive thing here is actually the recursion itself, with the *deeeeply* nested call tree.

And that's the key point here: It's a call ***tree***. Imagine what it is computing for a given number of steps, as a "pseudocode call hierarchy":

```
 compute(5)
  compute(4)
   compute(3)
    compute(2)
     compute(1)
      compute(0)
      compute(0)
     compute(1)
      compute(0)
      compute(0)
    compute(2)
     compute(1)
      compute(0)
      compute(0)
     compute(1)
      compute(0)
   compute(3)
    compute(2)
     compute(1)
      compute(0)
      compute(0)
     compute(1)
      compute(0)
      compute(0)
    compute(2)
     compute(1)
      compute(0)
      compute(0)
```

One can imagine that this grows *exponentially* when the number becomes larger. And all the results are computed hundreds, thousands or or millions of times. This can be avoided

---

### The fast solution

The key idea to make the computation faster is to use [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). This basically means that intermediate results are *stored* for later retrieval, so that they don't have to be computed again and again.

It's implemented in this example, which also compares the execution time of all approaches:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StaircaseSteps
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 5; i < 33; i++)
        {
            runStaircase(i);
            runSteps(i);
            runDynamic(i);
        }
    }

    private static void runStaircase(int max)
    {
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            sum += Staircase.counting(i);
        }
        long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Staircase  up to "+max+" gives "+sum+" time "+(after-before)/1e6);
    }

    private static void runSteps(int max)
    {
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            sum += Steps.step(i);
        }
        long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Steps      up to "+max+" gives "+sum+" time "+(after-before)/1e6);
    }

    private static void runDynamic(int max)
    {
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            sum += StaircaseDynamicProgramming.counting(i);
        }
        long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Dynamic    up to "+max+" gives "+sum+" time "+(after-before)/1e6);
    }
}

class Staircase
{
    public static int counting(int n)
    {
        if (n < 0)
            return 0;
        else if (n == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return counting(n - 1) + counting(n - 2) + counting(n - 3);
    }
}




class Steps
{
    static int c2 = 0;
    static int stairs;

    public static int step(int c)
    {
        c2 = 0;
        stairs = c;
        return step2(0);
    }

    private static int step2(int c)
    {
        if (c + 1 < stairs)
        {
            if (c + 2 <= stairs)
            {
                if (c + 3 <= stairs)
                {
                    step2(c + 3);
                }
                step2(c + 2);
            }
            step2(c + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            c2++;
        }
        return c2;
    }
}


class StaircaseDynamicProgramming
{
    public static int counting(int n)
    {
        int results[] = new int[n+1];
        Arrays.fill(results, -1);
        return counting(n, results);
    }

    private static int counting(int n, int results[])
    {
        int result = results[n];
        if (result == -1)
        {
            result = 0;
            if (n >= 1) 
            {
                result += counting(n-1, results);
                if (n >= 2) 
                {
                    result += counting(n-2, results);
                    if (n >= 3) 
                    {
                        result += counting(n-3, results);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result += 1;
            }
        }
        results[n] = result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

The results on my PC are as follows:

```
...
Staircase  up to 29 gives 34850335 time 310.672814
Steps      up to 29 gives 34850335 time 112.237711
Dynamic    up to 29 gives 34850335 time 0.089785
Staircase  up to 30 gives 64099760 time 578.072582
Steps      up to 30 gives 64099760 time 204.264142
Dynamic    up to 30 gives 64099760 time 0.091524
Staircase  up to 31 gives 117897840 time 1050.152703
Steps      up to 31 gives 117897840 time 381.293274
Dynamic    up to 31 gives 117897840 time 0.084565
Staircase  up to 32 gives 216847936 time 1929.43348
Steps      up to 32 gives 216847936 time 699.066728
Dynamic    up to 32 gives 216847936 time 0.089089
```

---

Small changes in the order of statements or so ("micro-optimizations") may have a small impact, or make a noticable difference. But using an entirely different approach can make the *real* difference.

Comment: Very cool answer with dynamic programming ! It's funny, but I thought about going about it in that exact way, but got myself completely twisted around when it came to actually counting the ways, and my brain telling me "No, DP would give you the shortest path but here you need to hit every step in every possible way." Then, I thought about using a n-step map and applying it over the remaining stairs, but nothing from Collections was allowed for that section of questions (since others were asked to build lists, stacks, etc.), but couldn't find the right way to store it in an array in time.